# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have error in this when I upload the data from .csv file from other php file, and my error is :-
"**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near** "

```
function array_to_sql($queryData , $table , $multiple = true){

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root", "", "mydata");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

    //If multiple data
else
{
    foreach($queryData as $queryEntry)
    {
          if (count($queryEntry) > 0) {
              foreach ($queryEntry as $key => $value) {
                  $value = "'$value'";
                  $updates[] = "$key = $value";
              }
          }

          $implodeArray = implode(', ', $updates);
      //print_r($updates);
      $sql = "INSERT INTO `$table` (`".implode("` , `",array_keys($queryEntry))."`) VALUES('".implode("' , '",array_values($queryEntry))."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE $implodeArray";


        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Request Updated";
        } else {
            echo "Error: ". "<br>" . $conn->error . $sql;
        }
    }                 
  }     
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSV fields contain spaces, which is not allowed for MySQL field names.

You need to manipulate `$key`  or put it in quotes as is

```
     if (count($queryEntry) > 0) {
          foreach ($queryEntry as $key => $value) {
              $key='`'.$key.'`';
              $value = "'$value'";
              $updates[] = "$key = $value";
          }
      }
```